# Attempted to set the key with value on object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen. [ Angular2 + React Native ]

Tags: android, angular, react-native, mobile-application

I working on an mobile app with Angular2 + React Native and When i try to execute below code:

```
<Text [styleSheet]="styles.button" opacityFeedback (tap)="showMore=!showMore" testID="Show_More">
    {{showMore ? 'Hide more' : 'Show more'}}
  </Text>
```

i am getting following error:

[image]

It was working fine previously then not sure what had changed..?? May be react native version or something because code is just same..

Can anybody help me with this??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

10 months too late, but I think you've got too many sets of curly braces; try

`{showMore ? 'Hide more' : 'Show more'}`

instead of

`{{showMore ? 'Hide more' : 'Show more'}}`